# If the default initial value of PriorityBlockingQueue is 11 then why does remainingCapacity method return Integer.MAX_VALUE?

Tags: java

and when I add values, why does the `remainingCapacity()` value remains the same?

```java
PriorityBlockingQueue<Integer> pbq = new PriorityBlockingQueue<Integer>();
pbq.add(1);
pbq.add(1);
pbq.add(1);
pbq.add(1);
System.out.println(pbq.remainingCapacity());
```

output is: 2147483647

Answer (score 2):

`remainingCapacity` returns the number of elements you could still add to the queue. In the case of a `PriorityBlockingQueue`, there is no hard limit, so it returns `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, as specified in the [`BlockingQueue.remainingCapacity()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#remainingCapacity())'s javadoc:

> Returns the number of additional elements that this queue can ideally (in the absence of memory or resource constraints) accept without blocking, or `Integer.MAX_VALUE` if there is no intrinsic limit.

The initial capacity, on the other hand, is the initial size the internal array will be created. This doesn't mean the queue won't accept another item after the eleventh one, but that the internal data structure will have to be resized at this point, incurring a performance penalty.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is exactly what it says in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html#remainingCapacity--):

> Always returns Integer.MAX_VALUE because a PriorityBlockingQueue is
> not capacity constrained.

You are perhaps confusing the initial capacity of some structure used in the implementation, versus the capacity of the queue itself.  The initial capacity affects initial storage allocation, i.e., how many elements the queue can hold before storage expansion is needed.